# How to use FormArray in Angular4 (strange behavior)

Tags: forms, angular

I am trying to produce a form value of the following object:

```
{
  party: 'Birthday Party"
  guests: [
   {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}
   {firstName: 'Mona', lastName: 'Lisa'}
  ]
}
```

I have the following form control using FormBuilder:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  party: '',
  guests = this.fb.array([{
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  }])
});
```

My HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="party" formControlName="party">
  <div formArrayName="guests">
    <input type="text" placeholder="first" formControlName="firstName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="last" formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
  <button>+ADD GUEST</button>
</form>
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'guests -> firstName'
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'guests -> lastName'
```

I do not know how to handle the `(click)` function for the ADD GUEST `button`. How can I make it 'append' another guest in the form?

How can I add a validator to ensure that there is at least ONE guest before the form is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed wrong model to FormBuilder.array.

That's proper way:

```
  public form = this.fb.group({
party: 'test',
guests: this.fb.array([
 this.fb.group( {firstName: 'firstName', lastName: 'lastName'})
])
```

});

Check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/gbBzTeBgC9iH2YS1qkwl?p=preview

Comment: "*You passed wrong model to FormBuilder.array...*". I think it would be more useful if you could point here what is wrong and what you have fixed on your *plunker*... because there are 3 questions (bug + 2 questions) in OP and you didn't answer nothing. In addition, `Validators.minLength (<requiredNumber>)` is sufficient to validate the formArray (you do not need to create a custom validator).

Comment: Well some devs prefer code over describing. In addition, you can't achieve 'at least one' with only ng validators

Comment: Take it as a suggestion... check [**How To Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Yes, it's possible to check if the form has at least one `guest` using the in-built validator `minLength`: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlY6iD0V4aunmn4ga4I9?p=preview).

Comment: This is not a complete solution. It marks empty fields as valid. Adding Validators.required for each formControl does not solve that problem because we have condition at least one valid. But does not matter. You rule! gn

Comment: Hmm, yes, if you want to check it has at least one `VALID`, the custom validator is the way to go, if no, either `minLength` or `required` works perfectly.

Comment: This helped me get started.. thank you @DawidWiniarczyk

Answer (score -2):

in the [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) is shown that you need to specify your `form` like this:

`<form [formGroup]="form">
...
</form>`

and not as its written in your example

Comment: Sorry, I was writing a metaphor example and I forgot to include it. It does exist in my real component. Also, I'm trying to do something similar to this: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-field/

Comment: the link is broken